# strange distortion of videos in VLC

Tags: resolution, vlc, totem, 15.04

I'm not sure how to describe this problem, but I have screenshots! I'm trying to watch a video on VLC (VLC 2.2.0 on Ubuntu 15.04). Fullscreen, the vertical resolution appears to be too low. In a window, there are dot artefacts strewn about all over the video. When I play the same video in Totem, it looks fine. What could be the problem? Screenshots are below...

Here's what the video looks like in *Totem*:

[image]

Here's what it looks like in fullscreen VLC (note the poor vertical resolution):

[image]

For clarity, you can see the difference here:

[image]

Here's what it looks like in windowed VLC (note the dot artefacts):

[image]

What's going on?

---

EDIT: When I try the video in SMPlayer, I see similar artefacts to those in VLC.

Comment: the solution proposed in this [link][1] worked for me


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/616010/vlc-video-playback-is-choppy-on-vivid-with-nvidia-346

Comment: Hey! Your suggestion was successful at removing the artefacts. Thanks for that! :) Setting output to "XVideo output (XCB)" or "Automatic" produces the artefacts, while setting to "OpenGL GLX video output (XCB)"  seems to get everything working fine.