# VLC video playback is choppy on Vivid with nvidia-346

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, video, vlc, opengl

I'm running Kubuntu Vivid, and have an Nvidia 940GM card on my Inspiron laptop. When using the nvidia-346 driver, VLC plays choppy videos (video seems "pixelized" with green dots appearing).

The situation doesn't happen with the nouveau driver, nor does it happen with other players. How can I fix this? I tried different GPU accelerations and shutting it off (that's what I found after googling) but it doesn't help. I had the same problem running 14.10.

Comment: have you tried checking different video outputs in vlc's Preferences->Video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing VLC's video output to OpenGL in Preferences → Video worked to fix this problem.

(Thanks to [wedu](https://askubuntu.com/users/59065/wedu) for [suggesting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616010/vlc-video-playback-is-choppy-on-vivid-with-nvidia-346/616020#comment868230_616010) to check the available video options. I'm not sure why I hadn't thought of that.)